# The trajectory of the midpoint of perimeter-bisecting pair of points of a closed convex curve and its area

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

Given a closed convex curve $C\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, there is a continuous family of pair of points in $C$ that bisects the perimeter of $C$. The midpoint of such pair draws a closed curve inside $C$; call it $m(C)$. If we define the area of a curve $C$ as the infimum of $\mu(S)$ s.t. $C\subset S$ and $S$ simply connected, we can calculate the ratio between the area of $m(C)$ and the area of $C$; call this $r(C)$. What is $\sup r(C)$? In other words, how can $m(C)$ be large compared to $C$? $r(C)$ admits the value $\frac{1}{16}$ when $C$ is a equilateral triangle, and intuitively this seems to be the maximum.